# MVC4 Mobile Template Script Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently playing around with the MVC4 Mobile template and am having a stressful time getting a particular view to render its javascript.

On my MediaView.chtml View I have the following tag:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/pyg/pyg-player.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This tag works great when I navigate **directly** to the view, but when use the default Index page on the template, and click my action link, the page performs its little transition effect and the script fails to load properly.

[image: Chome Network Output]
It looks like jquery is performing the loading of the script during the load, is there any way to prevent jquery from taking responsibility of the loading?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just experienced an issue transitioning from desktop web development to mobile development. Since MVC4 template is using Jquery Mobile, only the first page is rendered. All subsequent requests are made by ajax and thus the scripts are never properly loaded.  What you need to do is instead of binding on $(document).ready() you need to bind to **pageinit**

```
$( document ).delegate("#aboutPage", "pageinit", function() {
  alert('A page with an ID of "aboutPage" was just created by jQuery Mobile!');
});
```

More information can be found on the jQuery Mobile site.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html